# anaconda/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available

Tags: dll, linker, anaconda, deep-learning, caffe

I am running caffe on Ubuntu 14.04 with anaconda.

When I run `examples/mnist/train_lenet.sh`

> ```
> ./build/tools/caffe: /home/kli/anaconda/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/kli/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4)  
> ./build/tools/caffe: /home/kli/anaconda/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8)
> I0303 22:05:06.373118 11808 caffe.cpp:185] Using GPUs 0
> I0303 22:05:08.649866 11808 caffe.cpp:190] GPU 0: GeForce GTX TITAN X
> ```

I don't know what's wrong. 
This seems like some warnings, since the training process is OK.

> ```
> I0303 22:11:11.745873 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 100, loss = 0.227769
> I0303 22:11:11.745945 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.227769 (* 1 = 0.227769 loss)
> I0303 22:11:11.745960 11855 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 100, lr = 0.00992565
> I0303 22:11:11.943850 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 200, loss = 0.155188
> I0303 22:11:11.943912 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.155188 (* 1 = 0.155188 loss)
> I0303 22:11:11.943928 11855 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 200, lr = 0.00985258
> I0303 22:11:12.132534 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 300, loss = 0.160685
> I0303 22:11:12.132566 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.160685 (* 1 = 0.160685 loss)
> I0303 22:11:12.132580 11855 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 300, lr = 0.00978075
> I0303 22:11:12.320441 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 400, loss = 0.0642169
> I0303 22:11:12.320477 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.064217 (* 1 = 0.064217 loss)
> I0303 22:11:12.320490 11855 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 400, lr = 0.00971013
> I0303 22:11:12.528359 11855 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 500, Testing net (#0)
> I0303 22:11:12.635912 11855 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.972
> I0303 22:11:12.635975 11855 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.0880498 (* 1 = 0.0880498 loss)
> I0303 22:11:12.636888 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 500, loss = 0.121124
> I0303 22:11:12.636927 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.121124 (* 1 = 0.121124 loss)
> I0303 22:11:12.636947 11855 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 500, lr = 0.00964069
> I0303 22:11:12.827488 11855 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 600, loss = 0.0760444
> I0303 22:11:12.827522 11855 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0760446 (* 1 = 0.0760446 loss)
> ```

Comment: Maybe the required version of libTIFF is different to the installed version. [see this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/ztYL3skgKq0)